# Block Parallels Desktop from connecting to domain without using `/etc/hosts`

Tags: network, dns, parallels-desktop, hosts, domain

I have the following lines in my `/etc/hosts`. Parallels Desktop keeps commenting lines which as it needs to connect to that domain. I tried changing access of `/etc/hosts` to 444 but it suddenly changed to 644.

It seems like Parallels Desktop needs to edit `/etc/hosts` to define hosts on its local network.

How can block access of Parallels Desktop from these domains without changing `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 2):

### Configure Parallels Desktop to stop editing `/etc/hosts`

You don't mention which domains you are trying to block access to, but you can configure Parallels Desktop to stop fiddling with `/etc/hosts`, which will hopefully prevent this issue.

According to this [Parallels Knowledge Base article](https://kb.parallels.com/en/123300), you can prevent Parallels Desktop from updating `/etc/hosts` as follows:

1. Open the `/Library/Preferences/Parallels/network.desktop.xml` file and locate the following line:

   `<NATDAllowEtcHostsWrite>1</NATDAllowEtcHostsWrite>`
2. Set the setting above to "0" (disabled) so that no records will be created in the `/etc/hosts` file.

**Note that turning this setting off won't let you access a VM by hostname. Instead, you will have to use its IP address, which can be inconvenient, for example when connecting with SSH to a VM.**

**More information**

In Parallels Desktop Pro Edition a virtual machine's name will be automatically registered in the host's /etc/hosts records if the following statements are true:

- The VM is in Shared or Host-Only network mode;
- and the VM gets an IP address from DHCP (not a static).

For example, say you have a VM named `rhel6.3` which is in shared networking mode with the DHCP-assigned IP `10.211.55.4`. When you start the VM, a new record will be created in `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.211.55.4 rhel6.3 rhel6.3.shared #prl_hostonly shared
```

Now, by using either the `rhel6.3` or `rhel6.3.shared` name, this VM can be accessed from the host or any other VM in the shared networking group.

### Use firewall software

Alternatively, if the above method doesn't work, you can block the domains by using a firewall software like [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) (Little Snitch offers a free trial).

Comment: Do you understand *why* Parallels is adding itself to Hosts? As in, what is it trying to achieve? As a non-user of Parallels, this seems fairly invasive.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy The rationale behind this is that the user can then access a VM **by hostname instead of by IP address**, which is certainly convenient, for example when connecting with SSH to a VM. However, I agree with you, and would expect this to be: 1) disabled by default 2) easily configurable with the GUI instead of with some obscure XML file.

Comment: Thanks! I would encourage you to add the rationale to your answer. This will also let people know the consequences of turning it off.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Good point, I've expanded the answer with the rationale.